# Is there a way to implement Morse code inside an array?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, microcontroller

I'm making my microcontroller display letters of the alphabet in Morse code using LEDS (dot == short blink, dash == long blink).

I could make a switch statement and do it like this :

```
switch (input)
case "a | A" 
.... 
case "b | B "
....
```

but then I'd have a 27+ long switch statement, so I guess that's not very good?

I was thinking of making an array with all the Morse code inside but how do I implement this concept, that the first entry of the array equals a or A, ... ?

Comment: Have you considered using a lookup table? And you can use `tolower`/`toupper` to avoid the hassle of having to work with both upper and lower case letters.

Comment: `char morse[CHAR_MAX + 1][MAX_MORSE_LEN + 1] = {..., "---", ..., "...", ...}; /* I only know SOS */` and then just `printf("%s", morse['A']);`, but the `case 'A': case 'a':` approach is good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that your platform uses a character-encoding system in which the 26 Latin alphabet letters have consecutive values (the most common system used, ASCII, does, but it's *not* guaranteed by the C Standard), then we can define an array of strings for the Morse code for each letter and index into that array using the value of a given letter from which the value of `'A'` has been subtracted.

We can also do a similar thing for digits (these *are* guaranteed by the Standard to have contiguous codes).

Here's a sample code (we convert all letters to uppercase before indexing into the Morse array):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    const char* Alpha[26] = {
        ".-",   // A
        "-...", // B
        "-.-.", // C
        "-..",  // D
        ".",    // E
        ".._.", // F
        "--.",  // G
        "....", // H
        "..",   // I
        ".---", // J
        "-.-",  // K
        ".-..", // L
        "--",   // M
        "-.",   // N
        "---",  // O
        ".--.", // P
        "--.-", // Q
        ".-.",  // R
        "...",  // S
        "-",    // T
        "..-",  // U
        "...-", // V
        ".--",  // W
        "-..-", // X
        "-.--", // Y
        "--.."  // Z
    };
    const char* Digit[10] = {
        "-----",// 0
        ".----",// 1
        "..---",// 2
        "...--",// 3
        "....-",// 4
        ".....",// 5
        "-....",// 6
        "--...",// 7
        "---..",// 8
        "----.",// 9
    };
    char input[256];
    do {
        printf("Enter text ($ to quit): ");
        scanf("%255s", input);
        printf("Morse code...\n");
        for (char *c = input; *c; ++c) {
            if (isalpha(*c)) printf("%s", Alpha[toupper(*c) - 'A']);
            else if (isdigit(*c)) printf("%s", Digit[*c - '0']);
            else if (*c != '$') printf("<error>");
            printf("\n");
        }
    } while (input[0] != '$');
    return 0;
}
```

If we can not rely on contiguous codes for the letters (or choose not to, for a more robust implementation), we can determine the index by calling the `strchr` function (we must then `#include <string.h>`) to get our letter's position in a list of all letters:

```c
    //...
    const char* Letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    //...
        if (isalpha(*c)) printf("%s", Alpha[strchr(Letters,toupper(*c)) - Letters]);
```

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Alternatively you can just sacrifice a bit of read-only memory and store 127 entries. Gives faster look-up and you don't have to worry about them EBCDIC computers with non-contiguous symbol tables that everyone insists on being portable with.

Comment: @Lundin Good point(s). But OP seemed unsure how to index an array where the *first entry of the array equals A or a* ... so I showed how to do that using the subtraction of 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Adrian's, just encode most of the ASCII character set - from space (32) to capital Z (91). You'll get numbers, letters, punctuation, and pro-signs, and some we don't care about, but who cares, because it simplifies things **so** much. You're on a 8-bit microcontroller, so you don't have to worry about character encoding and OS preferences and all that trash.

Further more, skip the strings. They'll just take up room in your limited RAM, unless you do the `F("asd")` trick with Arduino to put them in flash. Instead of strings, use ones and zeros:  `0b0110000` read from left to right to get dot, dash, sentinel stop bit, followed by padding zeros. Looks nasty but really isn't.

Here's what I have...

```
/*
 * Bit packing: read left to right from MSB, 0=dit, 1=dah,
 * with extra dah terminating sentinel, then zero filled on right.   
 * Example,
 *      letter D   -..          "dahdidit"
 *      convert    100
 *      terminate  1001
 *      pad        10010000
 *      result   0b10010000
 * To use, test the top bit, send dit or dah, shift left, end when result is $80.
 */

/*
 * the character codes are in ASCII order, 
 * from space $20 to underscore $5F or 32-95 decimal.
 * lower-case alpha should be coverted to upper-case before lookup
 */
    
const charcodes[] PROGMEM = {
    0,          // $20    space
    0b10101110, //  ! exclamation point /KW
    0b01001010, //  " double quote      /AF
    0,          //  # hash mark, octothorpe
    0b00010011, //  $ dollar sign       /SX
    0,          //  % percent sign          or /KA ?
    0b01000100, //  & ampersand     /AS
    0b01111010, //  ' single quote      /WG
    0b10110100, // $28  ( left parenthesis  /KN
    0b10110110, //  ) right parenthesis /KK EOW ?  EOM
    0b00010110, //  * asterisk      /SK
    0b01010100, //  + plus sign
    0b11001110, //  , comma
    0b10000110, //  - dash, hyphen      /DU
    0b01010110, //  . period
    0b10010100, //  / slash, divide     /DN
    0b11111100, // $30  0
    0b01111100, //  1
    0b00111100, //  2
    0b00011100, //  3
    0b00001100, //  4
    0b00000100, //  5
    0b10000100, //  6
    0b11000100, //  7
    0b11100100, // $38  8
    0b11110100, //  9
    0b11100010, //  : colon         /OS
    0b10101010, //  ; semicolon     /KR
    0,          //  < less-than sign
    0b10001100, //      = equal sign        /BT
    0,          //  > greater-than sign
    0b00110010, //  ? question mark
    0b01101010, // $40  @ commercial 'at' sign  /AC
    0b01100000, //  A
    0b10001000, //  B
    0b10101000, //  C
    0b10010000, //  D
    0b01000000, //  E
    0b00101000, //  F
    0b11010000, //  G
    0b00001000, // $48  H
    0b00100000, //  I
    0b01111000, //  J
    0b10110000, //  K
    0b01001000, //  L
    0b11100000, //  M
    0b10100000, //  N
    0b11110000, //  O
    0b01101000, // $50  P
    0b11011000, //  Q
    0b01010000, //  R
    0b00010000, //  S
    0b11000000, //  T
    0b00110000, //  U
    0b00011000, //  V
    0b01110000, //  W
    0b10011000, // $58  X
    0b10111000, //  Y
    0b11001000, //  Z
    0,          //  [ left bracket
    0,          //  \ back-slash
    0,          //  ] right bracket
    0,          //  ^
    0b00110110, // $5F  _ underscore        /IQ
};


/*
 * look up the code for an ASCII character
 * return 0 for bad characters and characters out of range.
 */
byte getcode(char c)
{
    // convert upper-case to lower-case
    if ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
        c -= 'a' - 'A';
    // check for characters beyond our table
    if ( c < ' ' || c > '_' )
        return 0;
    // else read the byte from flash
    return pgm_read_byte(charcodes + c - ' ');
}
```

I'm sure the smart folks will find problems, and I'll learn from them.  Have fun!

EDIT: and they did! @Clifford pointed out that I didn't show how to use the encoded byte. So here it is... you'll have to define your values for length of dit, dah, element gap (between dits and dahs), character gap (between characters) and word gap (between words):

```
#define TOPBIT 0x80

void key(byte c)
{
        // while we're not done, start the tone, delay a bit, stop the tone
        while ( c != TOPBIT && c != 0 ) {
                tone(BUZZ, FREQ);
                digitalWrite(LED, 1);
                delay( (c & TOPBIT) ? dahLen : ditLen );
                noTone(BUZZ);
                digitalWrite(LED, 0);
                delay(elemGap);
                // shift left one place; test the next bit the next time around
                c <<= 1;
        }
        // now generate a character space
        delay(charGap - elemGap);
}
```

HTH! (Thanks @Clifford)

Comment: You might include code for interpreting the encoding to translate it to ./_ - it is not entirely obvious.  You have to scan the byte for the terminate flag to know when to stop.  To that end it would be simpler to put the padding in the MSBs and have a "start" flag rather than a "terminate" flag as you don't know it is a termination unless you have looked ahead at the padding.  So your example becomes 0b01110011, though choosing a symmetrical example is itself ambiguous.  If you were to read it from LSB first, it would work as a start flag, but your other encodings suggest MSB first.

Comment: Yes, checking for a ending of 1 would be easier in some sense, but it would be harder to construct and read the table. Test for a final 1 or a final $80 is not *that* much different. At least that was my thought at the time. And you are correct - I neglected to show how to use the encoded byte. I've added the code.

Comment: Reading left-to-right required a top-down bit order. (it wouldn't let me edit this in)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my point, but I also misunderstood your encoding.  As I said using an palindromic example was a bad idea.

Comment: I think I see... I'm using a fixed mask and shifting the byte upwards; you're shifting the bit-mask down and leaving the byte alone. Yours has the extra search-where-to-start phase, but otherwise cleaner. Thanks!  (the original method doesn't need to look ahead; it just stops when all that's left is the sentinel stop bit.)

Comment: Indeed.  I realised by mistake. I though you had the dot/dash bits in MSBs, the LSBs (in reverse order).  My error The advantage of using the MSB is the bits are in the "natural" order, so more intuitive when reading the code, but computationally no benefit.